# PHP Header doesn't work in web expressions 4

Tags: php, header, expression-web

I am using header to redirect to a page:

```
ob_start();
header('Location: index.php');
```

It is working fine when i open the page directly from browser or any other editor.
BUT it doesn't works when i open it through Microsoft expression web 4, which is my editor.

Comment: I don't know Microsoft expression web 4, but, if it's your editor, then I assume you use it to modify / write your code, why would it execute the php?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

- In the Site Settings dialog box, on the Preview tab, select Use Microsoft Expression Development Server, and then select For only PHP and ASP.NET web pages.

**By default, Expression Web locates the php-cgi.exe file installed at C:\PHP or C:\Program Files\PHP. If you installed PHP in a different location, or if the text box under Path to PHP executable for previewing PHP pages in this website is empty, under Path to PHP executable for previewing PHP pages in this website, click Browse, locate and select php-cgi.exe, and then click OK.**